# jQuery each() and multiple Ajax calls - elements in Ajax don't match parents in iteration

Tags: jquery

I have an each() function that iterates across a number of tr elements, in reverse (lol).

```
<table>
    <tr><th>header row</th></tr>
    <tr><td id="row1">row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="row2">row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="row3">row 3</td></tr>
</table>

$($("table tr:gt(0)").get().reverse()).each(function() {
     tr=$(this);
     console.log(tr); // correctly prints my TRs in reverse order
}
```

Works great, but now watch:

```
$($("table tr:gt(0)").get().reverse()).each(function() {
    tr=$(this);
    console.log(tr); // correctly prints my TRs in reverse order
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "ajax.php",
         data: data,
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(json) {
             console.log(tr); // incorrectly prints TRs in not-reverse order
             // TRs are not matched with above. Chaos ensues.
         }
    });
});
```

I figure what's happening is the Ajax call is taking longer to execute than the iteration over than the TR elements... I suppose I could set `async` to `false`, but **is there a way to keep this asynchronous?**

**SOLUTION**

As @Nicola pointed out below, it's probably best to just send the  ID to the server along with the Ajax call and retrieve it again in the success function.

Comment: Use the `var` keyword so your variable is correctly scoped, rather than being global. As it stands, all of your success callback functions are using the exact same variable (and therefore print out whatever its value is when they run), rather than using the value that was intended for that callback to use.

Comment: Actually, wow... that's a really simple solution. I think that works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are firing one ajax call for every `<tr>` and since calls are asynchronous, you have no guarantee that they will return in order, that means that the second call is fired just after the first call is fired, withouth waiting for a response. Setting `async` to `false` solve the problem, if you want to keep things "async" you should fire the second call in the success callback, but your iteration won't wait, so you need to refactor everything

Comment: Yes, I agree... but is there an asynchronous solution for defining the `tr` and retrieving the same one inside the ajax call?

Comment: @AlexMoore send one request not one per row

Comment: @Nicola, I think you mean setting `async` to `false`?

Comment: @AlexMoore the problem is that you are redefining `tr` while iterating, one thing you could do is to send the current `tr` to your server in some way and then have the server send it back to you.

Comment: @Nicola, this is the probably the best solution for this particular problem. Thanks!